# ms teams deep link not working for ios app

Tags: ios, microsoft-teams, deep-linking

I need your help, I am developing a bot for ms teams and in my scenario the user must be redirected from chat to tab, for this I use a deep link here is an example link

```js
`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/${process.env.APPLICATION_ID}/${process.env.TAB_ID}`
```

and it works great everywhere in the browser in the desktop version and in window and in ubuntu and even on Android, but as it turned out, it does not work on IOS, and specifically in the ms teams application for IOS

[image]

however in the app on IOS I get the following.

Any hints and tips any advice that can help me solve this problem

**UPDATE:** a small addition today I put a desktop application on a macbook and there was no such problem. So the problem occurs only in the mobile application

Comment: Format: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/<entityId>?webUrl=<entityWebUrl>
<appId>: The ID from your manifest.
< entityId>: The ID for the item in the tab, which you provided when configuring the tab.
<webUrl>: An optional field with a fallback URL to use if the client does not support rendering the tab.
Even though mentioned as optional, I suspect webUrl missing is the problem here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try this one. Now I found an open issue https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/3223 but it turns out that the problem occurs not only for me

Answer (score 0):

We have a backlog bug item for this and will inform you if it gets resolved.

Comment: Can you please share the Bug report link

Answer (score 0):

There was a fix done for this issue in latest store app. It's working now. Please check.