# MSTeams Deep Link not working in iOS in chats only

Tags: ios, botframework, microsoft-teams, deep-linking, adaptive-cards

I'm generating adaptive cards in Microsoft Teams with the following deep link:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000aaa00b/my-tab-id?context=%7B%22channelId%22:%2219:aaaaaaaa000000000000000000000000@thread.tacv2%22,%22subEntityId%22:%22link/2%22%7D&webUrl=https://my-app/url
```

which is generated like so:

```
const conversationType = context._activity.conversation.conversationType;
const channelId = context._activity.channelData.channel?.id;

const BASE_DEEP_LINK_URL = ({ entityId, context, entityLabel, entityWebUrl }) =>
    encodeURI(
        `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/${APP_ID}/${entityId}?label=${entityLabel}&context=${context}&webUrl=${entityWebUrl}`
    );

const viewNeedDeepLink = BASE_DEEP_LINK_URL({
    entityId: groupId,
    context: JSON.stringify({ ...(conversationType === 'channel' && { channelId }), subEntityId: `needs/${id}` }),
    entityLabel: name,
    entityWebUrl: `${BASE_URL}/${instanceId}/groups/${groupId}/needs/${id}`
});
```

This works as expected in Desktop (channel and chat) and iOS (channels only) - When in channel it opens the link in the channel tab and then sends the subEntity parameter to the application as context. When in chat, it opens the personal app instead of the chat tab since there's no way I could find to pass a "chatId" or something of the sort as context to the deep link (I followed [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-your-tab)).

However when in chat and while on iOS, the deep link just throws an alert with ["Link not supported"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y70ot.png) when clicked

Am I missing something on the `context` object when it's a chat? currently it's only passing `channelId` if `conversationType ===  'channel'` because like I mentioned above I wasn't able to find how to specify a `chatId`.

Comment: Are you trying to create deeplink to a Chat? If yes then go through below doc for deeplink format to a chat.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generate-a-deep-link-to-a-chat

Comment: No, the deeplink is meant to be linking to our custom tab, which may be in a channel or a chat

Comment: We see this case on stack overflow that may indicate that there was possibly an issue on Microsoft’s end last year. It was not confirmed in the thread though whether it was actually resolved or not. Do you have any details behind this fix and whether it’s potentially recurring or whether it was potentially never fixed for chat? We are concerned there are could be a microsoft bug because we don’t have this issue on any other devices. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67525677/ms-teams-deep-link-not-working-for-ios-app

Comment: We have created openurl button in adaptive card. And in openurl we have tried the deeplink in chat. Its working fine at our end. We have tested on IOS 15.3 and Teams version 3.22.0. 
Could you please update the IOS and Teams version and check again.

Comment: the issue got resolved yesterday without us changing anything on my end - "link not supported" alert doesn't appear in iOS anymore

Answer (score 1):

We have created openurl button in adaptive card. And in openurl we have tried the deeplink in chat. Its working fine at our end.

Following document refer for generating deeplink to tab.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generate-a-deep-link-to-your-tab

Tested on: IOS 15.3 and Teams version 3.22.0.